# I am getting supervisor process ERROR (spawn error)

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean, supervisord

I am trying to host a django project using gunicorn, supervisor and nginx. I configured gunicorn it's running well. but supervisor process is getting errors.

Here is my conf:

```
[program:leadscrapper.nl]
command = /root/venv/bin/gunicorn_start
user = root
stderr_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/test.err.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/supervisor/test.out.log
autostart=true
redirect_stderr = true
environment = LANG=en_US.UTF-8,LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

The traces:

```
root@scrapper:~# supervisorctl start leadscrapper.nl
leadscrapper.nl: ERROR (spawn error)
```

What can be the issue and how can I solve this issue?